# django not able to access jsonfield data in templates

Tags: json, django, postgresql

Actually, I don't know how to access jsonfield data in the template. I tried something like this

```
{% for key in place.places_to_visit %}
    {{ key }}:{{ value }}
{% endfor %}
```

But it is showing all json data that I have added including {} and " " and also same for Arrayfield of characters
I also want to add an image in that jsonfield, how to do that? Does that image need to be media directory and then I should include its path? Or some other ways to do that?
It is also showing error as follows

```
"[05/Sep/2017 23:03:00] "GET /ontheway/1/ HTTP/1.1" 200 4238"
```

jsonfield data of places_to visit is

```
"Places to visit": [
           {
              "name" : "some name",
              "overview" : " some data",
              "iamge": "image path"
             }
            {
              "name" : "some name",
              "Overview": " some data",
              "image": "image path"
             }
           ]
```

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try to use `items`:

```
{% for data in place.places_to_visit %}
    {% for key, value in data.items %}
       {% if key == 'image' %}
           <img src="{{ value }}">
       {% else %}
           <div> {{ key }}:{{ value }} </div>
       {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: can your show `place.places_to_visit` by simple add `{{ place.places_to_visit }}` to the template, please add result as text formated to the question, by edit it

Comment: glad to help you, please, don't forget accept the answer

Comment: Yeah working thank you . But I have couple of problems 1. Image is not getting displayed instead its path is displayed so can you tell me how to add image in JSONfield and 2nd is everything is displaying on single line .I want new entry on new line So how to do it?

Comment: updated try it, i hope the image path it is real url for image, other way you will not see the image

Comment: Do i need to add an image in static files or any other path will be ok?

Comment: i think you need detail description with real example of data, and it better to create new question for it.

Comment: Ok i will post another question